# React-Native: How do I specify either 'INSendMessageIntent' or 'INStartCallIntent' in the value of the NSUserActivityTypes Info.plist

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I was trying to upload a react-native expo app, I just built and I keep getting this error.

**ITMS-90894: Missing Info.plist value**

Since I am using expo, I don't know how to add this in my `app.json` file

`"ios": {"supportsTablet": true, "infoPlist": { "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Enable access your photos"}, },`

I would really appreciate an example. Thank you,

[image: ITMS-90894: Missing Info.plist value]

Comment: Any update ? Did you managed to get this working ?

Comment: Yes I did. I will share it below

Comment: On my side I'm struggling with push notifications ... But seems that you only use camera :/, thanks anyways your answer could help someone :)

Comment: I could assist, send me a link to your post.

Comment: It's linked to firebase FCM : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257229/fcm-send-a-notification-to-ios-device-using-expo-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution...

```
"infoPlist": {
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Enable appName to...microphone...",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Enable appName to access camera ...",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Enable blah to access photos...",
        "NSUserActivityTypes": [
          "INSendMessageIntent"
        ]
      }
```